# An implication of weak convergence of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I've been stuck on the proof of the following lemma and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Suppose we have a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n \in m_1(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathcal{B})$ that converge weakly to $\mu \in m_1(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathcal{B})$ then it follows that $\forall f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n;[0,\infty))$ we have that,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d\mu \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d\mu_n.$$

The proof proceeds as follows. Set $f_k=min(f,k)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ then $f_k \to f$ monotonically. Hence by the monotone convergence theorem we conclude that,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d\mu = \lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_kd\mu = \lim_{k\to \infty}\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_k d\mu_n \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f d\mu_n.$$

Where the first equality comes from MCT and the second comes from a previous proven result that I wont state here and the the part that I'm completely at a loss for is the inequality at the end. If anyone could maybe explain this last step in more detail I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What does the notation $m_1(\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{C})$ mean? Looks like a complex-valued measure to me, but then $\mu_n$ wouldn't be a probability measure.

Comment: Sorry there are some typos that i now see ill fix them. The space where f lives was edited and so the space of measures as you pointed out.

Comment: I see, thanks. Then the answer to your question is not difficult: Just note that $0 \leq f_k \leq f$ implies $\int f_k \, d\mu_n \leq \int f \, d\mu_n$. Using this estimate, the limit $\lim_k$ drops away and your get the inequality, which you are looking fir.

Comment: Thank you! so much for this, I kinda feel a bit silly now.